# FIM Import error for one user

Tags: user-profile-service

I have got one user that is causing the user profile sync to error, if I remove the OU the user is in from the sync it works ok. I have thought about deleting and re-creating the user, but that seems like a bit of a cop out!

In the FIM client I am getting the following error

ma-extension-error

and in the detail

```
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: More than one DN specified for the same profile.
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ProfileImportExportService.UpdateWithProfileChangeData(Int64 importExportId, ProfileChangeData[] profileChangeData)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle._InvokeMethodFast(Object target, Object[] arguments, SignatureStruct& sig, MethodAttributes methodAttributes, RuntimeTypeHandle typeOwner)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean skipVisibilityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.WebServiceDirectProxy.WebMethodInfo.Invoke(Object webServiceInstance, Object[] args)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.WebServiceDirectProxy.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] args)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ManagementAgent.ProfileImportExportDirect.UpdateWithProfileChangeData(Int64 importExportId, ProfileChangeData[] profileChangeData)
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles.ManagementAgent.ProfileImportExportExtension.Microsoft.MetadirectoryServices.IMAExtensibleCallExport.ExportEntry(ModificationType modificationType, String[] changedAttributes, CSEntry csentry)
```

I cant see anything wrong with the user, in the research I have done it seems to point to the samAccountName being duplicated, but i didn't think this was possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to fix this, but i'm not really sure how so I a bit annoyed!! The only thing i did was move the user out of its orignal OU, add the offending OU back to sync settings and re-run a sync.

All the accounts came over fine, so i added the offending user back into the OU, ran the sync again and it worked fine!

Comment: How did you determine which user was causing the error?

Comment: Using the FIM client i could see the users that were failing in its logs

Answer (score 2):

You didn't mention the version, so I assume you have SharePoint 2010.

Binging around it appears to be one of two issues.

1. Have you tested and ensured that you don't have a duplicate sAMAccountName. (I am not sure how this happens but you should be able to do an LDAP query to figure it out, or dig deeper into the MIISClient logs for the offending account.
2. You may have a corrupt profile record for the user. You could try to save the user entered values for the record by using PowerShell, Delete it, and reimport the records. SharePoint will recreate the record. Then you could restore the user entered values from your copy.

Matthew

Here is the thread: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sharepointadminprevious/thread/9ebba287-c94c-408a-afbb-3e6a280c17be/

Comment: I deleted the profile out of Sharepoint first, that seemed to make no difference. I have managed to get it working now though